# Perfomance improvement by using glsl

Tags: python, kivy, glsl, kivy-language

my game animation performance isn't fast enough so i tried looking for a way to improve speed and found [Shoot em up](https://github.com/cr8ivecodesmith/kivy-shmup/blob/master/shmup/app.py)  but the  game seems to use GLSL script and canvas which i really don't understand how they works. How can i rewrite my code by using the above method (glsl script and canvas)

Here is my slow script 10-12 Fps on Mobile (android and iOS) and 48-58 Fps on desktop

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, ReferenceListProperty, ObjectProperty,ListProperty, BooleanProperty
from kivy.vector import Vector
from kivy.clock import Clock
import random
import math
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string("""
<FT>:
    canvas.before:
        PushMatrix

        Rotate:
            angle: self.angle
            origin: self.center
    canvas.after:
        PopMatrix
<Flame>:
    canvas.before:
        PushMatrix

        Rotate:
            angle: self.angle
            origin: self.center

    canvas.after:
        PopMatrix
<FlameGun>:
    tank: tank
    canvas:
        Rectangle:
            source: "wood.png"
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    FT:
        id: tank
        center: (root.width/2, 70)
""") 
class Flame(Image):
    velocity_x = NumericProperty(0)
    active = BooleanProperty(False)
    velocity_y = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity = ReferenceListProperty(velocity_x, velocity_y)
    angle = NumericProperty(0)
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Flame, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.size_hint=(None, None)
        self.source = "zn.zip" #Contain animated images of Flame
        self.anim_delay= 0.35
        self.anim_loop = 1
        rs = random.randint(70, 80)
        self.size = (rs, rs)
        self.bind(active=self.addV)
    def addV(self, *args):
        self.velocity_y += random.uniform(20.0, 25.0)
        self.velocity_x += 0
    def move(self, pa):
        self.pos = Vector(*self.velocity) + self.pos
        self.angle = random.randint(0, 360)
        self.size = (self.size[0]+1, self.size[1]+1)
        if (self.y > pa.top/1.6):
            pa.removeThis(self)
            self.velocity_y = 0
            self.velocity_x = 0
class FT(Image):
    velocity_x = NumericProperty(0)
    activated = BooleanProperty(False)
    velocity_y = NumericProperty(0)
    velocity = ReferenceListProperty(velocity_x, velocity_y)
    angle = NumericProperty(180)
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(FT, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.source = 'FlameThrower.png'
class FlameGun(Widget):
    tank = ObjectProperty(None)
    angle = NumericProperty(180)
    pr = NumericProperty(0.0)
    flames = []
    def update(self, dt):
        self.addFlame()
        if len(self.flames) != 0:
            for tank in self.flames:
                if tank.active:
                    tank.move(self)

    def removeThis(self, bl):
        self.flames.remove(bl)
        self.remove_widget(bl)
        bl = None
    def startFlame(self, *args):
        for tank in self.flames:
            if not tank.active:
                tank.active = True
    def addFlame(self, *args):
        self.fl = Flame()
        self.add_widget(self.fl)
        self.fl.center = self.tank.center
        self.flames.append(self.fl)
        self.fl.velocity = 0, 0
        if len(self.flames) != 0:
            self.startFlame()
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        self.tank.activated = True

class FlameApp(App):
    def build(self):
        game = FlameGun()
        Clock.schedule_interval(game.update, 1.0 / 60.0)
        return game

if __name__ == '__main__':
    FlameApp().run()
```

how can i rewrite the above code  using glsl for the fastest performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say exactly why your code is slow without profiling it, but it's quite possible it's due to over-use of widgets. Try using Kivy canvas instructions instead as much as possible - this requires more manual management of exactly what goes where, but avoids a great deal of widget overhead (which doesn't matter for most apps, but is a problem when you have a very large number of widgets).

As it happens, this is exactly what you were asking about: Kivy is an opengl toolkit and canvas instructions directly manipulate the gl state with relatively little overhead. The example you linked does some even more manual things, but you don't need to go that far for now.